# Get auto generated sequence in postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql

I retrieved some city names from a table but along with names I want to show an auto generated Id eg:

```
    name | id
-------------------
    New Delhi | 1
    Kanpur | 2
    Mumbai | 3
```

How could i achieve this in PostGreSql? I don't wan't to generate a sequence and use nextval('sequence_name').

query for retrieving names: `select city_name as name from cities;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `row_number()` function in Postgres's [window functions](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/functions-window.html)

As per documentation

> row_number() - number of the current row within its partition, counting
>   from 1

```
select city_name as name
      ,row_number() over() id 
from cities;
```